# Google Login via eww

Tags: eww, google-docs

I am trying to login to my google account via eww, but eww just hangs with the following message:

> Loading https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password...

I have multifactor authentication setup for Google, and am not sure if eww supports this.

I have verified that I can connect https protocol by visiting https://example.com.

Is this a bug in eww or is there something that I am missing.